# Como remover o primeiro caractere de uma string numa Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

No **PostgreSQL 9.2** tenho uma coluna com as seguintes informações:

```
A101
B12
C3
```

Preciso de um comando para selecionar e outro para atualizar essa coluna removendo o primeiro caractere ficando assim:

```
101
12
3
```

Tentei resolver com a função *substring*, mas não consegui chegar no resultado esperado.

Como resolver?

Comment: Tenta essa query: `UPDATE tabela SET coluna = RIGHT(coluna, LEN(coluna) - 1)`. Essa deve atualizar a coluna.

Comment: @Dvdsamm, esse comando é para SQL Server, meu SGDB é PostgreSQL, mesmo assim obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como passou que sua coluna da qual não deseja o primeiro caractere, então, vamos considerar todo e qualquer tipo de caractere.

Para selecionar os dados removendo o primeiro caracter, e usando o `SUBSTR`, podemos fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(info,2,LENGTH(info)) 
  FROM INFORMACAO
```

<sub>Exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6d7c4c/9</sub>

> **Função substr:**
>   `substr(string, from [, count])`
>   Sendo o primeiro parâmetro o texto, o segundo o inicio da contagem de
>   caracteres do texto, e o terceiro o total de caracteres.

Dessa forma, então passamos que precisará pegar a partir do segundo caractere, até o tamanho total do texto, conseguimos isso através da função `lenght`, que calcula o total de caracteres em um texto.

Agora para atualizar ao coluna, usamos as mesmas funções citadas:

```
UPDATE informacao 
   SET info = SUBSTR(info,2, LENGTH(INFO));
```

Existe outras formas de fazer o que espera, mas fiz utilizando o `substr` do qual foi citado na pergunta, para ter um maior aprendizado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

O correto seria assim:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(info,2,LENGTH(info)**-1**) 
  FROM INFORMACAO
```